# How to get view name from SqlDataReader?

Tags: sql, .net, view, sqldatareader, getschematable

From sql I need to get columns, tables and views names.
With this solution I am able to get only base table names and columns but not the view names.

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
   foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
 
var baseTableName = row["BaseTableName"].ToString(),
var columnName = row["ColumnName"].ToString(),
var baseColumnName = row["BaseColumnName"].ToString()                   
}
```

For example:
My view:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 as 
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id1 = table.id2 

sql = "select col1, col2 from view1"
```

then I get:
BaseTableName: table1
BaseColumnName:col1
ColumnName:col1

BaseTableName: table2
BaseColumnName:col2
ColumnName:col2

I can't get view name from sql. So instead of table1 and table2 I would like to get view1. I tried with all different CommandBehavior options. Any ideas? 
I use .NET Framework 4.7.2